# Program doesnt find relative file when run from withing Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fstream

I am using visual studio 2019. I was doing this process to try to read the data from files but on the visual studio I am unable to. It just shows blank screen, no error or such.
Then I used an online ide but the program was able to read the file online. I can't figure out the issue. It's the same code that is used on both.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

The following is the code written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream inputfile;
    string name1, name2, name3;

    inputfile.open("names.txt");

    inputfile >> name1;
    inputfile >> name2;
    inputfile >> name3;

    inputfile.close();

    cout << name1 << endl;
    cout << name2 << endl;
    cout << name3 << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you try for a specific path like "C:\\names.txt"?
if it work, check your "name.txt" location and make sure is correct

Comment: what happens if you press f10 and step through your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your projects from within Visual Studio, your current working directory becomes where your `main.cpp` resides (see the note at the end), not the executable directory. Therefore your program can't find the `names.txt` and hence what you see.

So you can verify that by going into your Release/Debug directory (depending on which configuration you are building your project for) and execute your program. You'll see it will find the file and work just fine.

You can change your working directory from `Properties\Debugging` `working directory` option and setting it to something like : `$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\`

Here's a simple demo how this in fact works in action:

[image]

### Note

I assume your `main.cpp` resides inside your project directory where `.vcxproj` and the likes reside. So its more correct to say the current working directory by default is where your project file (`.vcxproj`) resides and not your cpp files as they can be placed anywhere.

Comment: sorry for being dumb. i'm sort of a noob at this. so what you are saying is that the .cpp where i am working right now is where the file needs to be(which i want to read data from)?       i did move the file to that .cpp source file but still the same issue.

Comment: You are using a relative path and that relativity is usually in regards to where your program is executed from. This is called current working directory. basically when you run your executable, and your program reaches `names.txt`, it will first search in the current working directory i.e. same directory your executable is run from. when you run/debug from within Visual Studio, the current working directory is set as the current project directory, that is where your cpp file exists. hence when your program tries to find the file, it doesnot exist in the current working directory

Comment: i.e. in your project directory where your cpp file exists.

Comment: What @Rika is saying is correct. When you are debugging, you can set the debugging options of the project to set the working directory. If you set the working directory to where the file exists, it will open. Otherwise, the output of the compiler defaults to putting the .exe file into a directory .\debug in relation to the .vcxproj file. (usually) Since the exe and the txt file are not in the same directory, it will always fail.

Comment: I also need to add that my assumption was that your .cpp file resides next to your project files. @JosephWillcoxson actually made a very good point and is correct. I updated the answer to reflect this as well to clear any confusion my simplification may have brought.

Comment: thank you all for bearing with me and helping me with this confusion. the code works now  and I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: @KamaljitBhuller Please accept the answer then so this question is marked as completed.